# Running package.json scripts of external libraries JS

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a created library that has a script called `"versionator": "node app.js"` inside package.json.
But currently, other projects that download this library can only use it by importing the module as:

```
const versionator = require("versionator")
versionator()
```

Is there a way that i can run the script called "versionator" that is inside my library folder from another projects that download this lib?

**repo:** https://github.com/sousadiego11/versionator-js

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to specify a `bin` object inside your package.json

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#bin

```
{
  "bin": {
    "versionator": "./app.js"
  }
}
```

This will create a bin called versionator.

Edit:

As CherryDT pointed out in his comment you can call it then via

```
npx versionator
```

Comment: If you look at the repo, the package.json contains a  "bin": "app.js", but running "npm run versionator-js" with the lib installed it only says "missing script versionator-js". @Johannes Merz

Comment: have you tried leading`./`, so `./app.js`

Comment: also have a look at your `node_modules/.bin` folder, anything in there?

Comment: just looked at it, seems i have everything i need. i'm posting a image of how i'm trying to use my lib, and its files.

Comment: _but running "npm run versionator-js" with the lib installed it only says "missing script versionator-js"_ - yes, because there is no _script_ `versionator-js` in the outer package's `package.json` with that name, instead it's a binary provided by your package! You need either `npx versionator-js` or - if installed as local dependency - `./node_modules/.bin/versionator`.

Comment: Thx @CherryDT for pointing that out, totally missed the run in Diegos comment!